# How to ensure uniqueness, of more than 1 column, of data table, in vb.net?

Tags: .net, datatable, unique, having

I am working in VB.NET.
I have a DataTable, say dt = New DataTable()
I have three columns, say TeacherID, SubjectID, and TeachingGrade
Now, I want [TeacherID - SubjectID] pair, not to repeat.
Both are integers.
Unique setting to columns, ensures uniqueness individually, problem ya..
Then legal data is also rejected.
HOW TO?

Comment: I know, PK takes care of uniqueness. But I have already used this PK mechnism to other columns. Now, I will construct Another example to explain scenario better. Consider table, FamilyMembers where my PK is (FamilyID + MemberID) both integers. There is another column, MemberName (string). Now, I want to have uniqueness On columns, (FamilyID + MemberName). Tell me please, now, HOW TO?

Answer (score 0):

Set these columns as the primary key for the table:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataColumn teacherIdColumn = dt.Columns.Add("TeacherId", typeof(int));
DataColumn subjectIdColumn = dt.Columns.Add("SubjectId", typeof(int));
dt.Columns.Add("TeachingGrade", typeof(int));
dt.PrimaryKey = new[] { teacherIdColumn, subjectIdColumn };
```

---

EDIT:

You can also create a constraint on the table:

```
dt.Constraints.Add(new UniqueConstraint(new[] { teacherIdColumn, subjectIdColumn });
```

Comment: Thanks. I know, PK takes care of uniqueness. But I have already used this PK mechnism to other columns. Now, I will construct Another example to explain scenario better. Consider table, FamilyMembers where my PK is (FamilyID + MemberID) both integers. There is another column, MemberName (string). Now, I want to have uniqueness On columns, (FamilyID + MemberName). Tell me please, now, HOW TO?